# How to get Device Feature Information in Android?

Tags: java, android

I want to display the device Feature information used by my application. For example: Information like this

```
android.hardware.location.network
android.hardware.wifi
com.google.android.feature.GOOGLE_BUILD
android.hardware.telephony
android.hardware.location
android.software.sip
android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch
glEsVersion = 2.0
```

i used following code:

```
PackageManager packageManager = mcontex.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    FeatureInfo[] feature = packageManager.getSystemAvailableFeatures();
    String k = null;
    for (FeatureInfo s : feature) {
        k = s.name + "\n" + "glEsVersion =" + s.reqGlEsVersion;
    }
    return k;
```

It displays only glEsversion but rest it show null. Any suggestion?

Comment: FeatureInfo[]  is array and String k is signal variable its return only last value from array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always overwrite k but if i understand you correctly you want all features in one String

```
for (FeatureInfo s : feature) {
    k =k+ s.name + "\n" + "glEsVersion =" + s.reqGlEsVersion;
}
```

Comment: You answer is correct. I made little change in the code.            for (FeatureInfo s : feature) {
   if(s.name ==null){
    s.name = "";
   }
   k = k + s.name + "\n";
   l = "glEsVersion =" + s.reqGlEsVersion;
  }
      z = k + l;
  return z;